# How can i use SoapException on .NET (not framework)?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I need to get information from SoapException.Detail.LastChild.(Is XmlNode class)
My application target is .NET Standart 2.0.

I tried to use FaultException but there is no information about SoapException.Detail.LastChild.InnerText.

I need this information, screenshot from SoapException: https://prnt.sc/yzhu1TajL9iU

With FaultException there is no such information: https://prnt.sc/wjU_p6_0Ilf6

Which class is the substitute for SoapException in .NET(not framework)?

Comment: You have displayed the details on the screenshot about faultDetails variable. Can you debug and get the details on FaultException ex variable first and check whether it contains the right values?

Comment: Yes, i had checked it firstly. I check it again. this is the class information https://prnt.sc/iVon1YgfARHX. It just warns about exception that has been raised as a result of client data.

Comment: By the way i am implementing web services of UPS courier.

Comment: I think what @shehanpathirathna was saying was can you show us what `ex` (the instance of FaultException) contains before you do anything with it. It should contain the actual XML

Comment: Here is the screenshot of FaultException class https://prnt.sc/zIK3GaYZml_g